# script to generate diffs between consecutive commits, and writing them to file

Tags: svn, scripting, diff, for-loop

In order to view changes or diffs between commits, i use the following from the command line:

```
svn diff -r 3000:3025 > daychanges.diff
```

I want to modify the command so that it generates diffs between successive commits, concatenates them and outputs to file, something like

```
svn diff -r 3000:3001 > daychanges.diff
svn diff -r 3001:3002 >> daychanges.diff
svn diff -r 3002:3003 >> daychanges.diff
...
svn diff -r 3019:3020 >> daychanges.diff
```

how can i write such a script?

Comment: You forgot to say what you're running `svn` in.

Comment: i dont totally understand your comment. i am running svn for tracking a project, and using ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `for` loops in bash:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-generating-print-range-sequence-of-numbers.html

Given that, it shouldn't be all that difficult to write a script that calls `svn diff` over a range of commits.

In a single line command, that could be run from the CLI:

```
for ((start=3000,finish=3001; finish<=3025; start++,finish++)); do svn diff -r $start:$finish; done > out.file
```

or if you prefer, the shorter version,

```
for ((i=3000; i<3025; i++)); do svn diff -r $i:$(($i + 1)); done > out.file
```

In a multi-line script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$begin=$1
$end=$2
$outfile=$3

for ((start=$begin,finish=$begin+1; finish <= $end; start++,finish++))
do
    svn diff -r $start:$finish
done > $outfile
```

(Omit the `> $outfile` if you just want to manually direct the output of the script.)

Comment: i havent run your version yet, but i wrote svn diff -r $(i):$(($i+1)) >> file inside the loop, and it works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like:

`diffs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=$(($1 + 1))
last=${2}
for a in `seq $first $last`; do
    svn diff -r $(($a - 1)):$a
done > daychanges.diff
```

then:

```
./diffs.sh 3000 3020
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will parse the 'svn log' output for the commit numbers and diff the whole shebang (pardon the pun).. if you want to limit the commit range supply that in one argument eg, "-r88833:HEAD" ... no spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset last;
for r in `svn log $1|grep '^r'|awk '{print$1}'|sed -e 's/r//g'|sort`;do 
    if [ ! -v last ]; then 
        last=$r;
        continue; 
    fi;
    echo ------------------------;
    echo diff  $last:$r ; 
    echo ------------------------; 
    svn diff -r$last:$r;last=$r;
done>diffs
```